# jsPDF Table Width & Font Size

Tags: jspdf

I thought this would be relatively simple but I cannot find an answer anywhere, I have had a good hunt in Stack Overflow. Apologies if I have missed something obvious!

How on earth do you set the table width in jsPDF? I simply want my table to stretch to 100% of the page width. Here is the code I am using:

```
<script>
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    source = $('#pdf')[0];
    specialElementHandlers = {
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 40,
        left: 40,
        width: 600
    };
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source,
    margins.left, 
    margins.top, { 
        'width': margins.width,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        pdf.output('datauri');
    }, margins);
}
</script>
```

I am using standard, unformatted HTML table.

```
<table class="reference">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>       
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>      
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>        
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>        
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>        
        <td>67</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

The table only stretches about 60% across the PDF, which just seems to be a random amount. In addition the text inside the table is a different font and size to the text outside the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: remove margins left and right?